# Does Go optimize out unreachable if-statements?

Tags: if-statement, error-handling, go, assert

Go has a very unfortunate lack of built-in assertions. I want to implement them this way:

```
const ASSERT = true

func SomeFunction() {
        if ASSERT && !some_condition_that_should_always_be_true() {
                panic("Error message or object.")
        }
}
```

My question is will the if-statement be optimized out if I define `const ASSERT = false`?

Comment: The go spec doesn't enforce any dead code removal. A particular implementation is free to do so as aggressively as it sees fit.

Comment: @JimB  http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions evaluated at compile time?

Comment: @Uvelichitel: yes, but that has nothing to do with dead code removal. The compiler is still free to leave the if block in the compiled object.

Comment: @JimB: It does have something to do with it. What exactly is the difference between a constant expression and dead code? Dead code is only a bit more generalized to not only include expressions, but also statements.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I've done benchmarks, predictable branches often had much less effect than I expected, even in inner loops. I'd consider leaving the checks in at runtime unless you see problems because, e.g., the test itself is slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted by the people in the comments to your question, it's implementation-specific.

gc does remove it. You can build your program with `-gcflags '-S'` and see that the `ASSERT` part is not in the binary.

E.g. compile the following code with `-gcflags '-S'`, and you'll see that the code on lines 8 and 9 is included, but change `Assert` to be false, and they won't be there in the asm listing.

```
package main

const Assert = true

var cond = true

func main() {
    if Assert && !cond {
        panic("failed")
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As for gccgo, it removes this code at `-O1` and above. You can see it by compiling the same code with

```
go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags '-O1' main.go
```

and then doing

```
objdump -S main
```

to see the annotated assembly.

Comment: I never realized `objdump` had an `-S` option, thanks! (and thanks for the actual answer, too...)